# Error connecting to local installation of MongoDB thru terminal

Tags: mongodb

Terminal displays following error:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.5
connecting to: test
Wed Jul 24 14:26:45.779 JavaScript execution failed: Error: couldn't connect to server         127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L112
exception: connect failed
```

upon running
    mongod run --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf

I get following error on console:

```
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 11204
all output going to: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 100
```

The mongo.log shows:

```
***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
Wed Jul 24 14:39:57.360 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=11204 port=27017      dbpath=/usr/local/var/mongodb 64-bit host=59.161.67.13.del-cdma.dialup.vsnl.net.in
Wed Jul 24 14:39:57.363 [initandlisten] 
Wed Jul 24 14:39:57.363 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
Wed Jul 24 14:39:57.363 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.5 
Wed Jul 24 14:39:57.363 [initandlisten] git version:  a2ddc68ba7c9cee17bfe69ed840383ec3506602b
Wed Jul 24 14:39:57.363 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin bs-osx-106-x86-64-2.10gen.cc 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:32:41 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Wed Jul 24 14:39:57.363 [initandlisten] allocator: system
Wed Jul 24 14:39:57.363 [initandlisten] options: { bind_ip: "127.0.0.1", command: [ "run" ], config: "/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf", dbpath: "/usr/local/var/mongodb", fork: "true", journal: "true", logappend: "true", logpath: "/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log", port: 27017, quiet: "true" }
Wed Jul 24 14:39:57.367 [initandlisten] journal dir=/usr/local/var/mongodb/journal
Wed Jul 24 14:39:57.368 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Wed Jul 24 14:39:58.113 [initandlisten] couldn't open /usr/local/var/mongodb/test.0 errno:13 Permission denied
Wed Jul 24 14:39:58.136 [initandlisten] couldn't open /usr/local/var/mongodb/test.0 errno:13 Permission denied
Wed Jul 24 14:39:58.152 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10085 can't map file memory, terminating
Wed Jul 24 14:39:58.152 dbexit: 
Wed Jul 24 14:39:58.152 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Wed Jul 24 14:39:58.153 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Wed Jul 24 14:39:58.153 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Wed Jul 24 14:39:58.153 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Wed Jul 24 14:39:58.153 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Wed Jul 24 14:39:58.153 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Wed Jul 24 14:39:58.153 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Wed Jul 24 14:39:58.154 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Wed Jul 24 14:39:58.154 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
Wed Jul 24 14:39:58.154 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Wed Jul 24 14:39:58.154 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Wed Jul 24 14:39:58.154 dbexit: really exiting now
```

EDIT! ( trying suggestions from answers)
running $ mongod --repair gives the following error:

```
$ mongod --repair
Wed Jul 24 15:16:51.596 Can't specify both --journal and --repair options.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following command first to start the mongo server

```
mongod run --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

Assuming you installed mongo using [Brew](http://brew.sh/).

More information about the mongod process [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#using-mongodb-from-homebrew-and-macports)

**EDIT**

Try to repair mongo using :

```
mongod --repair
```

Seems to have issues with permissions also, try using `sudo` to start mongod

Comment: I have installed it using Brew. I am getting following Error:
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 11204
all output going to: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 100

Comment: please do `mongod --version` to see which mongod version you are using.

Comment: I am using: db version v2.4.5
Wed Jul 24 14:44:37.222 git version: a2ddc68ba7c9cee17bfe69ed840383ec3506602b

Comment: Its the latest one. I just updated it 1 hour back. (using brew)

Comment: which OS system are you using ? You might want to check out your brew installations using `brew doctor`. FYI, to update a brew formula your should first update brew using `brew update` then "upgrade" desire formula using `brew upgrade mongo`

Comment: I am using Mac OS X 10.7.4. I did run "brew update" before "brew update mongo". Like i said i have been following instructions on the link http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/ I have updated the question to demonstrate the errors and error log which is presently showing.

Comment: monged --repair not working. Brew doctor showing nothing significant. Only something pertaining to X-Code's command line tools.

Comment: yes. but Apple site is down. so can't do that, at the moment! :( but things are now in order! Thanks a ton! i'd vote up your answer if i could! God Bless.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you've actually started the server. It doesn't seem to be running here.

Comment: I just updated mongo by running $ brew update mongodb command. I'm following http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/ it says to run $ mongo next. What is the command to starting the server?

Comment: Great, but that doesn't start the server!

Comment: So how do i start the server?

Comment: I have answered this question above ;)